# Get current Credential Id selected in the current pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the Jenkins freestyle project, is there a way to fetch the selected credential Id?

I'm using the GitHub Branch Source Plugin.

The main goal of using the credentials is, I'm using the native `checkout scm` command to pull from source repo, then compile it and push it to another repo. In order to push to the second repo, I'm using the credentials.

As of now, I'm hard coding the credential Id as shown below.

```
 environment{
    CREDS = credentials('credential1')
    }
  steps{
    sh 'git clone sh 'git clone https://$CREDS_USR:$CREDS_PSW@github.xx.com/krishna/test-repo.git destination'
```

I do not want to hard code the credential id, but get the credential id from the one selected during configuration for `checkout scm`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withCredentials` like in example, where `credential1` with username and password:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credential1', passwordVariable: 'CREDS_PSW', usernameVariable: 'CREDS_USR')]) {
    sh "git clone https://$CREDS_USR:$CREDS_PSW@github.xx.com/krishna/test-repo.git destination"
}
```

Update:

```
environment{
    CREDS = credentials('credential1')
}

...

withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: CREDS, passwordVariable: 'CREDS_PSW', usernameVariable: 'CREDS_USR')]) {
    sh "git clone https://$CREDS_USR:$CREDS_PSW@github.xx.com/krishna/test-repo.git destination"
}
```

Comment: I'n using a similar way, I need to dynamically pull the credentialsId basing on the configuration of the pipeline

Comment: Dynamically pull from where?

Comment: The credentials configuration in the configuration window.

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single in command with variables.